# array of objects return the highest overall value from the latest date

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a similar structure:

```
var array = [
  {
    "overall": 8,
    "date": "2016-03-15",
    "review": "bla bla",
  },
  {
    "overall": 6,
    "date": "2016-01-19",
    "review": "asfasfsadfsd",
  },
  {
    "overall": 7,
    "date": "2016-01-23",
    "review": "adfsasfdasfas",
  }];
```

This return the highest value:

```
var highestScore = Math.max.apply(Math,array.map(function(o){return o.overall;}));
```

How can I filter this array to obtain the review that relates to highest overall value from the latest date? In this case "bla bla"

Comment: Would I be correct to assume you can have multiple values for the same date?

Comment: the example should show the problem, in other words, it should have 2 latest dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to sort the array, since you want to get only the highest value. So  use **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** and for comparing date string parse it using **[`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)** .

```js
var array = [{
  "overall": 5,
  "date": "2016-03-15",
  "review": "sadas sasdadasdas",
}, {
  "overall": 6,
  "date": "2016-01-19",
  "review": "asfasfsadfsd",
}, {
  "overall": 9,
  "date": "2016-03-15",
  "review": "sadas sasdadasdas",
}, {
  "overall": 7,
  "date": "2016-01-23",
  "review": "adfsasfdasfas",
}];

var res = array.reduce(function(a, b) {
  // parse the date
  var d1 = Date.parse(a.date),
    d2 = Date.parse(b.date);
  // if dates are equal compare value of overall and return value , else return based on date
  return d1 == d2 ? (a.overall > b.overall ? a : b) : (d1 > d2 ? a : b);
}).overall; // get overall value from final object

document.write(res);
```

Comment: The highest overall value from the latest date, what you are returning is the highest overall value only. In this case it would be five

Comment: should you compare `.overall` when the dates are the same so you can give the highest `.overall` value when there are tied dates?

Comment: I was just about to comment the same thing ^

Comment: This is by far the best answer so far

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.sort()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
var array = [{
  "overall": 5,
  "date": "2016-03-15",
  "review": "sadas sasdadasdas",
}, {
  "overall": 6,
  "date": "2016-01-19",
  "review": "asfasfsadfsd",
}, {
  "overall": 7,
  "date": "2016-01-23",
  "review": "adfsasfdasfas",
}];
var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aDate = Date.parse(a.date);
  var bDate = Date.parse(b.date);
  if (aDate > bDate) {
    return true;
  } else if(aDate == bDate) {
    return a.overall > b.overall;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
//hello
var isItMeYoureLookingFor = sortedArray[0];
```

Basically, sort with criteria, take the first one :).

Comment: I wouldn't use sort as we don't need a sorted array, just a single value. I'd personally prefer the other answer which uses `.reduce` (if it were updated to be technically correct for the question).

Comment: Why avoid sort so strongly? I like either approach, if this one is more readable to you or if you think the sorted array will be useful later on it's not like the sort will have performance issues in the large majority of cases.

Comment: It's just that `.sort` is unnecessary. Same reason I would use `.call` instead of `.apply` wherever possible. Using the right tool for the job, you know?

Comment: Another thing I would like to point out is that you're sorting the original array (making the new variable declaration redundant and kind of misleading). A possible caveat would be if the original array indexes were stored somewhere else they would most likely now be pointing to the wrong index.

Comment: I think with the context of the question , sorting could be a good idea. By the looks of things there isn't many items to sort in the array so it's not that computationally expensive, it is also declarative of the domain logic. I think sort is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain array iteration:

```
function newestHighestOverall(arr){
  if(arr.length == 0) return 0;

  var latestDate = new Date(arr[0].date);
  var highestOverall = arr[0].overall;

  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(latestDate < new Date(arr[i].date)){
        highestOverall = arr[i].overall;
        latestDate = new Date(arr[i].date);
    }else if(latestDate == new Date(arr[i].date)){
        highestOverall = Math.max(highestOverall, arr[i].overall);
    }
  }
  return highestOverall
}

console.log(newestHighestOverall(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` and first compare by `date` and then by `overall` and also return **review**.

```js
var array = [{
  "overall": 8,
  "date": "2016-03-15",
  "review": "bla bla",
},{
  "overall": 20,
  "date": "2016-03-15",
  "review": "Random bla bla",
}, {
  "overall": 6,
  "date": "2016-01-19",
  "review": "asfasfsadfsd",
}, {
  "overall": 7,
  "date": "2016-01-23",
  "review": "adfsasfdasfas",
}];

result = array.sort((a, b) => {
  return Date.parse(b.date) - Date.parse(a.date) || b.overall - a.overall;
})[0].review;
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I really like the logic of this answer but I still think `.reduce` would be better to use. I've made an example fiddle for you if you want to update your answer with it https://jsfiddle.net/bhn14gb8/1/